# Why is only the first row is being displayed from JSON list

Tags: json, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following table:

```
<div data-ng-app="myApp">
    <div data-ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <form>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>ID</b></td>
                    <td><b>Name</b></td>
                    <td><b>Surname</b></td>
                    <td><b>House</b></td>
                    <td><b>Address</b></td>
                    <td><b>Locality</b></td>
                    <td><b>Contact1</b></td>
                    <td><b>Contact2</b></td>
                    <td><b>Contact3</b></td>
                    <td><b>Reply</b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td></td></tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="telesale in telesales">
                    <td>{{telesale.ID}}</td>
                    <td>{{telesale.Name}}</td>
                    <td>{{telesale.Surname}}</td>
                    <td>{{telesale.House}}</td>
                    <td>{{telesale.Address}}</td>
                    <td>{{telesale.Locality}}</td>
                    <td>{{telesale.Contact1}}</td>
                    <td>{{telesale.Contact2}}</td>
                    <td>{{telesale.Contact3}}</td>
                    <td>{{telesale.Reply}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

controller:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

  myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

      GetPersons();

      function GetPersons() {
          $http({
              method: 'GET',

              url: '/api/data'
          }).
        success(function (data) {
            if (data != null || data != 'undefined') {
                console.log(data);
                $scope.telesales = data;
            }
        })
      .error(function (error) {
          $window.alert("Unable to retrieve people" + error.message);
      });
      }

  } ]);
```

The data is being retrieved from an api controller which returns a list of 40 objects, however only the first object is being displayed in the table. Why could this be happening?

Screenshot of some of the data retrieved from the api (data crossed out for privacy)[image]

It looks as if the second (and the rest of the objects) are being passed as localities which is an foreign key of another table[image]

API Code:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetPeople()
    {
        List<CommonLayer.Telesales> list = new BusinessLayer.Telesales().getUserSession(User.Identity.Name);
        //List<CommonLayer.Localities> list = new BusinessLayer.Localities().getAllLocalities();
        if (list.Count > 1)
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                Content = new StringContent(JArray.FromObject(list).ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
            };
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZAPESS4GHTqVx6Pdq28x?p=preview)

Comment: Could you provide a plunkr/jsfiddle please ?

Comment: I guess your problem is related to .net web-api rather than angularjs

Comment: @rikket do you expand your query in the api? it looks like, the telesales are expanded to your localities forth and back. so you have duplicate entries for your telesales.

Comment: You don't have an iterator around you table row to retrieve more than one result. Are you presenting each data row as a separate table in your output?

Comment: @GermannArlington what do you mean? When I tried to pass a normal list with 2 columns only and no foreign keys it all works good with no iterator

Comment: @RaphaelMuller I don't understand how it is being expanded, is there any way I can prevent that from happening?

Comment: please make plunker of fiddle

Comment: @AshishNautiyal Ok give me a sec

Comment: can you show me the api code? but, maybe you want the expanding, because you said, without the foreign key, everything worked.

Comment: @AshishNautiyal Plunkr here: (I added json data from the api in api/data because I did not know how to do it) http://plnkr.co/edit/GeC1U8bcqPYiGIBbzSNd?p=preview

Comment: @RaphaelMuller check updated, I added API Code

Comment: i updated your plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZAPESS4GHTqVx6Pdq28x?p=preview

Comment: I think your problem is in the API, you select only one telesale. you can also see this in the data.json in the new plunkr. where the first selected telesale is expanded to its localities and the locality expanded back with all included telesales. So you have to dig into your business logic to get all telesales you want. If you just want the telesales from this locality, you have to extract the data you already got in your json.

Comment: @RaphaelMuller the list returned from the API contains 40 objects, however for some reason in the json data they appear to be "nested" in the first row

Comment: In fact the same data in a normal table worked perfectly (using MVC foreach)

Comment: as you can see in the json file, the last 39 objects are just references. i think there lies the problem. MVC knows how to resolve the references. angularJS doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/fLb9VHrGNqMtouK3dMca?p=preview
it's workig but you should tune up your api to get data in better format

```
 function GetPersons() {
              $http({
                  method: 'GET',

                  url: 'data.json'
              }).
            success(function (data) {
              console.log(data)
                if (data != null || data != 'undefined') {
                    console.log(data[0].Localities.Telesales);
                    $scope.telesales = data[0].Localities.Telesales;
                }
            })
          .error(function (error) {
              alert("Unable to retrieve people" + error.message);
          });
          }
```

Comment: Logically that's not correct, or should not be the right way to do it

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that when you are loading the `Localities` navigation property, you are also loading the related `Telesales` to it.

In other words, the **whole** `Telesales` table is loaded just when you load the first object of it, because of it's navigation property `Localities` which in turn loads all the `Telesales` related to it, and as a result you get your whole table `Telesales` is loaded inside that navigation property `Localities`. Then when web-api tries to get the other `Telesales` objects, it finds they all have been loaded and replaces it with `$ref : RowId`

So, you need to reconsider your query, such that you don't load the `Localities` navigation property.

***Disclaimer***

you can try to parse your JSON data in a tool like [jsoneditoronline](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/) to see a pretty representation of what you get from server